# How do I update when I get this in terminal?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

How do I update when I get this message?
'''

```
base-files/jammy-updates 12ubuntu4.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 12ubuntu4.4]
gjs/jammy-updates 1.72.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.72.0-1]
libgjs0g/jammy-updates 1.72.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.72.0-1]
libmm-glib0/jammy-updates 1.20.0-1~ubuntu22.04.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.20.0-1~ubuntu22.04.2]
libvkd3d1/jammy 1.3~jammy-1 i386 [upgradable from: 1.1-5]
modemmanager/jammy-updates 1.20.0-1~ubuntu22.04.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.20.0-1~ubuntu22.04.2]
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

You need to run:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

See `man apt-get`:

```
upgrade
   upgrade is used to install the newest versions of all packages
   currently installed on the system from the sources enumerated in
   /etc/apt/sources.list. Packages currently installed with new
   versions available are retrieved and upgraded; under no
   circumstances are currently installed packages removed, or packages
   not already installed retrieved and installed. New versions of
   currently installed packages that cannot be upgraded without
   changing the install status of another package will be left at
   their current version. An update must be performed first so that
   apt-get knows that new versions of packages are available
```

To list the upgradeable packages again, after executing `sudo apt update`:

```
apt list upgradeable
```

Comment: Why downvoting a working answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can force apt to repeat your previous package management message by running the following command:

```
apt list --upgradable
```

The "upgradable from" packages are what is called "phased updates". Phased updates are software updates that are gradually rolled out to a subset of Ubuntu users rather than all users getting these updates at the same time. Upgrading these phased updates manually before apt is ready to install them normally can cause damage to your system, so it is recommended to wait until the phased update packages  are ready to be updated normally with `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` or by unattended upgrades without requiring manual intervention.